# How do I join two regular expressions into one in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, join, expression, notepad++

I've been searching a lot in the web and in here but I can't find a solution to this.
I have to make two replacements in all registry paths saved in a text file as follows:

1. replace all asterisc with: `[#42]`
2. replace all single backslashes with two.

I already have two expressions that do this right:

1st case:

Find: `(\*)` - Replace: `\[#42\]`

2nd case:

Find: `([^\\])(\\)([^\\])` - Replace: `$1$2\\$3`

Now, all I want is to join them together into just one expression so that I can do run this in one time only.
I'm using Notepad++ 6.5.1 in Windows 7 (64 bits).

Example line in which I want this to work (I include backslashes but i don't know if they will appear right in the html):

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\`

I already tried separating it with a pipe, like I do in Jscript (WSH), but it doesn't work here. I also tried a lot of other things but none worked.
Any help?
Thanks!

Edit: I have put all the backslashes right, but the page html seem to be "eating" some of them!
Edit2: Someone reedited my text to include an accent that doesn't remove the backslashes, so the expressions went wrong again. But I got it and fixed it. ;-)
Sorry, but this was my first post here. :)

Comment: I think you can't. Also `(*)` is not a valid PCRE regex.

Comment: If you wanted to replace `*` with `**` it could be done easily. But as it is, you don't have the flexibility to use 2 completely different replacements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everyone else already mentioned this is not possible.

**But**, you can achieve what you want in Notepad++ by using a Macro.

Go to "Macro" > "Start Recording" menu, apply those two search and replace regular expressions, press "Stop Recording", then "Save Current Recorded Macro", there give it a name, assign a shortcut, and you are done. You now can reuse the same replacements whenever you want with one shortcut.

Comment: Ooops! My damn pc just freezed in the exact moment that I was posting this and now I can't edit it... Well, thanks for the idea. That's a solution. :-)
I'm marking this as an answer. <br/>

But the system doesn allow me to vote on it. :( <br/>

For SYSTEM ADMINS:
I know I'm new here, but this is ridiculous not beeing able to vote on the answer for my own question. I'm a grown up with more than 20 years experience on IT. Why am I being treated as child?
You should change this policy. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Since your replacement strings are totally different and use data that come not from any capture (i.e. `[#42]`), you can't.

Keep in mind that replacement strings are only masks, and can not contain any conditional content.